# Apache Options -Indexes give me 404 instead of 403, why?

Tags: apache-2.2, indexes

I have an `Apache/2.2.21 (Debian)` webserver, which I disabled directory listing with `Options -Indexes` but now I got `404` error for a directory, but I think I should get a `403`.

I have no idea why I get 404, rather than 403.
What should I check?

I have disabled `autoindex` module, after it I got a `404` for every URL that request a directory listing (eg: `www.somesite.com/dir` ). How can I get a `403` for this. (The `dir` does exist)

As a try I also put `Options -Index` in the end of main config file (apache2.conf).

Comment: What makes you think that a 403 is the correct response?  The directory exists, but there's no web-accessible resource at the location - 404 is the proper response code.

Comment: Not necessarily; with -Indexes, its not that there's no resource--its that there's a resource that the user does not have access to.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem and I found that the solution is as simple as:

1. ENABLE mod_autoindex, otherwise you'll never get 403 for directory requests
2. DISABLE Indexes in directory's Options setting for obvious reason

Answer (score 0):

If you redefined Error 403 to **missing resource**, you'll get exactly this result
Check accesslog for requested URL

Comment: In the log I see 404 error.

Comment: Check accesslog for **requested URL**

Comment: The dir 2010 is exists on the site, and the following in the custom log:
`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Nov/2011:11:02:49 +0100] "GET /2010 HTTP/1.1" 301 545 "-" "CUT:browserinfo"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [16/Nov/2011:11:02:49 +0100] "GET /2010/ HTTP/1.1" 404 316 "-" "CUT:browserinfo"`

Comment: 301 status code in first answer means "for some reason redirect fired" obviously, and for **redirect target** (which doesn't exist) you get 404. At least I see it this way. Check httpd.conf or .htaccess for defined redirects